Typescript: Type is assignable to type T but T could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint error when passing function prop
I've seen quite a few questions about this error, mostly in the form of a function taking a generic that extends a type and expecting the return to be of the same type.
What I currently understand:

If you are returning something from the function that satisfies type T, TypeScript will still error because it cannot infer if it will match exactly the generic type (as it could have a number of extra properties)

I have a component that takes in a prop called itemSlot that is a function that will take a generic options param that will have id and description, and potentially more properties and return a ReactElement.


type Option = {
  id: string;
  description: string;
};

interface Props<P extends Option> {
  itemSlot?: ({ option }: { option: P }) => ReactElement;
}

const MultiSelectForm = <P extends Option>({
  itemSlot,
}: Props<P>) => {
  // ....
};



I am passing this to my return component inside MultiSelectForm like this


return (
  <MultiSelect
    ref={ref}
    itemSlot={itemSlot}
  />
);



Here are the types of my MultiSelect component


interface Props<P extends Option> {
  itemSlot?: ({ option }: { option: P }) => ReactElement;
}

const MultiSelect = <P extends Option>(
  { itemSlot }: Props<P>,
  ref: ForwardedRef<RefCallBack>,
) => {
  // ...
};

export default forwardRef(MultiSelect);



This is the exact error I'm getting:
Option is assignable to the constraint of type P, but P could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint Option
I'm not sure why it seems TypeScript is inferring the inputSlot prop of MultiSelect to be Option when I am defining it as a generic that extends Option?
I would be grateful for an explanation as there's some understanding still not clicking for me, as well as how to solve this?
Thank you!

Is this a [mre]? I've been trying to import necessary stuff from react but I keep seeing errors unrelated to your question. Please [edit] to make the code a self-contained example we can copy and paste into our own IDEs to see the problem you're seeing, without distractions like pseudocode or missing declarations, etc.
